# How can I draw a path from my location to another location?

Tags: android, maps

How can i draw a route between my location and another location without using the google navigation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer use this http://asmncl.blogspot.in/2012/04/android-draw-route-map-between-two.html with the location manager to get the lat & long of your current position